# Presenting a UIView without animation causes unexpected background colour in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have a view with background colour as "clear colour" in xib. While I am presenting that view using a `newViewController` (as `[self presentViewController:newViewController animated:YES completion: nil]`) it shows the `newViewController` animates from bottom, and works as expected.

But when I present that view controller without animation (as `[self presentViewController:addController animated:NO completion: nil]`), the background colour goes to the default gray colour in iOS 7.

Why is it so? Why is the background colour not showing as clear colour?

Comment: Have you tried setting the modalPresentationStyle like newViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyleOverCurrentContext;?

Comment: Yes I tried.... Bt result was same when present without animation